# Kotlin coroutine suspend error with Room DataSource.Factory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

## Overview

**Expected** - Successfully making a Room query for a `DataSource.Factory<Int, Content>` in order to populate a `PagedList`. This strategy is similar to the [Room  Coroutines](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5) implementation outlined in the Medium post by [Florina Muntenescu](https://medium.com/@florina.muntenescu) of the Android Developer Advocate team.

**Observed** - The app fails to build.

**Error**

Unfortunately, there is not a more specific error to suggest the source of the issue.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

## Implementation

*ViewModel*

1. The ViewModel uses `viewModelScope` to launch `getContentList()`.
2. `getContentList()` is a suspending function that calls the Repository with another suspending function `getMainFeedList()`.
3. In the `Loading` and `Error` cases a call to Room is made `queryMainContentList(...)`.

```
class ContentViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun processEvent(...) {
        ...
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _feedViewState.value = FeedViewState(contentList = getContentList(...))
        }
        ...
    }

    suspend private fun getContentList(...): LiveData<PagedList<Content>> =
            switchMap(getMainFeedList(isRealtime, timeframe)) { lce ->
                when (lce) {
                    is Loading -> 
                       coroutineScope { 
                          emitSource(queryMainContentList(...)) 
                       }
                    is Lce.Content -> lce.packet.pagedList!!
                    is Error -> 
                       coroutineScope { 
                          emitSource(queryMainContentList(...)) 
                       }
                }
            }
}
```

*Repository*

1. `getMainFeedList()` is a suspending function that uses `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` in order to get the coroutine scope.
2. `getMainFeedList()` returns LiveData with the result from a Firebase Firestore collection request, `contentEnCollection.get().addOnCompleteListener.`
3. The Firestore result is saved to a Room DB with `insertContentList()`, from within the nested suspending coroutine `launch { ... }`. **`insertContentList()` works as expected using `suspend`.**

```
object ContentRepository {
    fun getMainFeedList(...) =  liveData<Lce<PagedListResult>> {
            val lce = this
            val newContentList = arrayListOf<Content?>()
            contentEnCollection.get().addOnCompleteListener {
                arrayListOf<Content?>().also { contentList ->
                    it.result!!.documents.all { document ->
                        contentList.add(document.toObject(Content::class.java))
                        true
                    }
                    newContentList.addAll(contentList)
                }
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                   try {
                      database.contentDao().insertContentList(newContentList)
                   } catch (e: Exception) {
                      this.cancel()
                   }
                }.invokeOnCompletion { throwable ->
                   if (throwable == null)
                      lce.emit(Lce.Content(PagedListResult(
                         pagedList = queryMainContentList(timeframe),
                         errorMessage =  "")))
                   else // Log Room error.
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                // Log Firestore error here.
                lce.emit(...)
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun queryMainContentList(timestamp: Timestamp) =
            liveDataBuilder(database.contentDao().queryMainContentList(timestamp, MAIN))

fun liveDataBuilder(dataSource: DataSource.Factory<Int, Content>) =
        LivePagedListBuilder(dataSource,
                PagedList.Config.Builder().setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                        .setPrefetchDistance(PREFETCH_DISTANCE)
                        .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
                        .build())
                .build()
```

*Dao*

**`insertContentList()` works as expected.**

```
@Dao
interface ContentDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertContentList(users: ArrayList<Content?>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE timestamp >= :timeframe AND feedType = :feedType ORDER BY timestamp DESC")
    suspend fun queryMainContentList(timeframe: Timestamp, feedType: FeedType): DataSource.Factory<Int, Content>
}
```

## Stack Trace

The important part seems to be the following:

> **error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory).**

Here is the full log:

> 21:50:30: Executing task 'assembleAndroidTest'...
>
> Executing tasks: [assembleAndroidTest] in project /Users/adamhurwitz/Coinverse/android
>
> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
>   android.databinding.enableV2
>   Databinding v1 is removed.
>
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8.fullMode=true' is experimental and unsupported.
>   The current default is 'false'.
>
> WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getAssemble(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessManifest(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getPackageApplication(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
>
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
>   Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateSafeArgsDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild SKIPPED
>   Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:checkDebugAndroidTestDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
>   /Users/adamhurwitz/Coinverse/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1002: warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.
>   /Users/adamhurwitz/Coinverse/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1031: warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
>   Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugResources
>   Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
>   ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1/Users/adamhurwitz/Coinverse/android/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/app/coinverse/content/room/ContentDao.java:17: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory).
>       public abstract java.lang.Object queryLabeledContentList(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>   Note: [1](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5) Wrote GeneratedAppGlideModule with: [][WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor (NON_INCREMENTAL).
>                                        ^
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>     A failure occurred while executing > org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
>     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 9s
>   38 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 34 up-to-date
>   21:50:40: Task execution finished 'assembleAndroidTest'.

Comment: post full stacktrace

Comment: @JohnJoe, the full build output is `A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution` which only occurs upon implementing the above.

Comment: tried build and clean ?

Comment: I did build and clean as well as invalidating cache and restart.

Comment: Did you try to find out the full stack using "gradle->Tasks->build->assembleAndroidTest". I think it will provide detailed information about the error cause.

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadFarhan, I've included the stack trace above.

Comment: just remove the suspend from query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PagedList

A [`PagedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList) handles loading data on the background thread by default.

> If you use LivePagedListBuilder to get a LiveData, it will initialize PagedLists on a background thread for you.

- It is not needed to mark a Dao method as `suspend` that produces a `DataSource.Factory`. The return type is used by the annotation processor to know what kind of code to generate, just like the `suspend` modifier is.
- A `DataSource` when used together with a `LiveData<PagedList>` will execute queries off the main thread to safely call non-suspendable database and blocking network calls.

## LiveData

- There is no need to mark a DAO method that returns `LiveData` to be suspendable since the `ArchTaskExecutor` makes sure that queries are run off the UI thread, and results are delivered on the UI thread.
- To construct `LiveData` that calls suspendable methods, you can use the `liveData {}` builder extension from `lifecycle-livedata-ktx` extensions artifact.
- There is also a LiveData-builder that constructs a `LiveData<PagedList>` directly from your `DataSource.Factory`, check out the `paging-runtime-ktx` artifact.
- Also, I would not recommend returning `MutableLiveData` like that. Mutable livedata is usually mutated in private, and returned as a non-mutable `LiveData` object.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Carl B. I've removed the `MutableLiveData` from the Repository and replaced it with the `liveData` Kotlin coroutine builder. I'm not sure what you are referring to in regards to "_There is also a LiveData-builder that constructs a LiveData<PagedList> directly from your DataSource.Factory"_? The `LivePagedListBuilder` in the code above is already returning `LiveData`. Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: No problems. I was just saying that there is a Kotlin extension function available from Google that will produce a `LiveData<PagedList>` from your factory. Here's an example from an Architecture Components sample https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/repository/inMemory/byPage/InMemoryByPageKeyRepository.kt#L40

I also saw now that `DataSource` is deprecated and will be replaced with `PagedSource`, unsure when it will be released.

Comment: Thanks @Carl B, I've refactored to use the [`toLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data#construct-observable-list) extension function. Data is added with MutableLiveData in the Repository, then immutable LiveData is observed by the ViewModel to ensure data cannot be changed by the observer/ViewModel. The next step is to refactor to add data to a Kotlin [Flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8ppnjGPAGE&feature=youtu.be) in the Repository, and observe in the ViewModel.